# Group By and Sum from .txt file in Linux

Tags: linux, text, group-by, sum

Following a suggestion from @tripleee, I'm posting another question for a coding issue I'm having trying to be more specific with sources and expected results.

My source `.txt` file is quite over populated with lines and using `AWK`, I:

- extract only rows identified by a specific code.
- parse the content of the line in order to get only certain values.
- remove leading zeros from substring.

After these first steps, my saved output is like this (I can change the order of the columns as I wish).

```
1646         | 01         |       1602 |          4
1646         | 01         |       1604 |         19
1646         | 01         |       1605 |         35
1646         | 01         |       1606 |          7
1646         | 01         |       1607 |         37
1646         | 01         |       1609 |          9
1646         | 01         |       1610 |          3
1646         | 01         |       1611 |          2
1646         | 01         |       1612 |         90
1646         | 01         |       1613 |        107
1646         | 01         |       1614 |         12
1646         | 01         |       1615 |         12
1646         | 01         |       1616 |          4
1646         | 01         |       1617 |          1
1646         | 01         |       1618 |         39
3625         | 01         |       2311 |         14
3625         | 01         |       2312 |          9
3625         | 01         |       2313 |         11
3625         | 01         |       2314 |          3
3625         | 01         |       2315 |          1
3625         | 01         |       2316 |          1
3625         | 01         |       2317 |         28
3625         | 01         |       2318 |          9
3625         | 01         |       2320 |         12
3625         | 01         |       2321 |          5
3625         | 01         |       2322 |         29
3625         | 01         |       2324 |          3
1646         | 06         |       1600 |         12
1646         | 06         |       1603 |         19
1646         | 06         |       1608 |         11
3625         | 06         |       2319 |          6
3625         | 06         |       2323 |         16
3547         | AF         |       1525 |          1
3547         | AF         |       1526 |          1
```

What I would like to achieve is a group by on the second column, summing the fourth column, with a line for each value in the first column.

In other words, the expected output should be:

```
DEP         SUM
01
    1646    381
    3625    125
06  
    1646    42
    3625    22
AF  
    3547    2
```

Or with a better presentation:

```
DEP        | PDV        |            |        SUM
01         |            |            |          
           | 1646       |            |        381
           | 3625       |            |        125
06         |            |            |          
           | 1646       |            |         42
           | 3625       |            |         22
AF         |            |            |          
           | 3547       |            |          2
```

So far I've tried this:

```
awk '{sum[$2]+=$4}
END{for (date in sum) print date, sum[date], freq[date]}' Test_Awk_2.txt
```

But results in not what I expected:

> AF 2
>   01 506
>   06 64

Comment: You just need to use an array whose keys are `$3" "$1` and values are the sums.

Comment: @Barmar  
These are my tests:
```awk '{arr[$1]+=$4}
    END {for (key in arr) printf("%s\t%s\n", key, arr[key])}' Test_1646.txt \ | sort -k2,2  ```
```awk '{++freq[$3]; sum[$2]+=$1}
END{for (date in sum) print sum[date], date, freq[date]}' Test_1646_sorted.txt```

I've spent already some days on these issue. I wished to solve it alone, but if I'm asking for help, maybe it's because I'm stuck.
Not to mention to arrive at the script that I described in the questions.

Comment: Put the code in the question.

Comment: `$4` is the `|` separator column. Don't you mean `$7`?

Comment: You're only grouping by the `PDV` column, not `PDV` and `DEP`.

Comment: ```|``` delimits the column and it's used just for presentation with a printf.

Comment: You said that was the saved output, I naturally assumed you're processing that output as is.

Comment: What is the script you just added to the question? It doesn't look anything like the scripts in the comment. If that's the script that created the file, it's irrelevant to this question. Add the script that's trying to solve this problem, it doesn't matter how the file was created.

Comment: The key to your array should be `$1" "$2`, not just `$1`, so that you group by both columns.

Comment: ```awk '{sum[$2]+=$4}
    END{for (date in sum) print date, sum[date], freq[date]}' Test_Awk_2.txt
```
Result is:

AF 2 

01 506  

06 64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're only grouping your sum by one column, but you want to group it by 2 columns, so you need to use both of them as the key in the array.

You're also printing a `freq` array, but you never assigned it. It also doesn't exist in your desired output.

```
awk '{sum[$2" "$1]+=$4}
     END{for (date in sum) print date, sum[date]}' Test_Awk_2.txt | sort -n -k1,2
```

The `sort` command will put all the same values of `$2` in consecutive rows.

Comment: Thanks! Slowly I was getting there. I was missing the " " between $2 and $1.

Comment: I mentioned it twice in the comments.